# Solr spell check for phrases with multiple words

Tags: .net, solr, sitecore

If "heritga festiavl" is searched as a one sentence, Then expected result should be "heritage festival" or "heritag festi" but the suggestions are given individually for each word. is it possible to get suggestions as single phrase. if accuracy is added for words the suggestions are given clearly but accuracy varies based on words. for example if accuracy 0.86 work for word heritage to display results but the same accuracy doesn't work for word heart. Need suggestions that are with meaning.

**Sample result suggestion I got :**

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 37
  },
  "command": "build",
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  },
  "spellcheck": {
    "suggestions": [
      "heritg",
      {
        "numFound": 10,
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 7,
        "origFreq": 0,
        "suggestion": [
          {
            "word": "herita",
            "freq": 7
          },
          {
            "word": "heritag",
            "freq": 7
          },
          {
            "word": "herit",
            "freq": 7
          },
          {
            "word": "heritage",
            "freq": 7
          },
          {
            "word": "hearing",
            "freq": 6
          },
          {
            "word": "hiring",
            "freq": 5
          },
          {
            "word": "hertz",
            "freq": 1
          },
          {
            "word": "heig",
            "freq": 12
          },
          {
            "word": "heri",
            "freq": 7
          },
          {
            "word": "hert",
            "freq": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "heritga",
      {
        "numFound": 4,
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 7,
        "origFreq": 0,
        "suggestion": [
          {
            "word": "heritag",
            "freq": 7
          },
          {
            "word": "herita",
            "freq": 7
          },
          {
            "word": "heritage",
            "freq": 7
          },
          {
            "word": "herit",
            "freq": 7
          }
        ]
      },
      "festia",
      {
        "numFound": 5,
        "startOffset": 8,
        "endOffset": 16,
        "origFreq": 0,
        "suggestion": [
          {
            "word": "festiv",
            "freq": 14
          },
          {
            "word": "festiva",
            "freq": 14
          },
          {
            "word": "festi",
            "freq": 14
          },
          {
            "word": "festival",
            "freq": 14
          },
          {
            "word": "fest",
            "freq": 14
          }
        ]
      },
      "festiav",
      {
        "numFound": 4,
        "startOffset": 8,
        "endOffset": 16,
        "origFreq": 0,
        "suggestion": [
          {
            "word": "festiva",
            "freq": 14
          },
          {
            "word": "festiv",
            "freq": 14
          },
          {
            "word": "festival",
            "freq": 14
          },
          {
            "word": "festi",
            "freq": 14
          }
        ]
      },
      "festiavl",
      {
        "numFound": 3,
        "startOffset": 8,
        "endOffset": 16,
        "origFreq": 0,
        "suggestion": [
          {
            "word": "festival",
            "freq": 14
          },
          {
            "word": "festiva",
            "freq": 14
          },
          {
            "word": "festiv",
            "freq": 14
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "correctlySpelled": false,
    "collations": []
  }
}
```

Comment: This would depend on how the field is processed and what spell checker you're using. If the field you want as a suggestion only has the content `heritage festival`, a string field could work. Otherwise you might want to have shingles enabled for the field you use for spell checking.

Comment: spell checking is working based on DirectSolrSpellChecker dictionary. how could this be done via solr query.

Comment: Also how to disable word breaking dictionary based spell check

Comment: That would depend on the field type - the DirectSolrSpellChecker retrieves the suggestions from the tokens in the index; i.e. from what the processed form of what you've indexed for that field is. You need to have a list of filters that generate the tokens you want to compare the input against, possibly by using a KeywordTokenizer (if it's the only content for the field), or a Whitespace/Standard tokenizer with filters (for example the shingle filter) to get the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the need for phrases, you could try to set `spellcheck.collate` to `true` as described in the [documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/spell-checking.html).